# How to make Laravel Scout Database driver use trailing Wildcard for FULLTEXT index searches?

Tags: mysql, laravel, full-text-search, laravel-scout

I'm trying to improve performance of my searches, without implementing any specific search APIs such as elasticsearch or Algolia. I'm facing an issue where searching for part of a word on a FULLTEXT indexed column, even where I have 7 out of 8 characters of a word, I am getting 0 results. Seems it is trying to match the whole word (regardless of length), or I get nothing.

I've replicated the query Eloquent would be performing and the results (or lack there-of) in MySQL directly, and it seems that the query doesn't add a wildcard (*) to the end of the keyword, and I don't see an immediate way to force it to. Using the wildcard in MySQL I get the results I want, and it still seems to perform faster than a 'WHERE LIKE "%...%"' approach.

My question is, is there a way to make the query run using a wildcard at the end of the keyword?

I've added a FULLTEXT index to my Products table 'page_title' column, added the attribute to my Product model as such:

```
/**
     * Get the indexable data array for the model.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    #[SearchUsingPrefix(['code'])]
    #[SearchUsingFullText(['page_title'])]
    public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        return [
            'page_title'    => $this->page_title,
            'code'          => $this->code,
        ];

    }
```

Tried adding `#[SearchUsingPrefix(['page_title'])]` too, but that did nothing.

Performing searches on the model like this gives 0 results for queries including part of a word, for example, "fitte" (aiming for "fitted")

```
Product::search($q)->query(function($query){
                $query->select(['id', 'page_title as text', 'code as subtext'])->limit(5);
            })->get()
```

but doing this query manually like this with the same 'fitte' keyword gives me what I want (only searching one column here for sake of brevity)

```
Product::whereRaw("MATCH(page_title) AGAINST('$q*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
                ->select(['id', 'page_title as text', 'code as subtext'])->limit(5)
                ->get()
```

I'm running MySQL through XAMPP.